# Changing functionality of android standard buttons in AOSP

Tags: java, android, xml, android-source

I am developing android based educational device for students.
I have customized android open source project.
- changed launcher application
- deleted standard system apps
- added our apps.

Now i am struggling with changing functionalities of standard buttons like home, back and menu.

Please teach me how to customized standard buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to customize several files in AOSP to implement functions you need.
I have experienced with Android 6.0 so i will explain basing on this.

1.device/[company]/[type]/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/layout-sw600dp.xml
Here you can add or delete standard buttons

2.frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/NavigationBarView.Java
Here you can change functionalities of standard buttons.

I hope it will help you!